# Create a dom element from a separate html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, rendering

I have a single web app that uses javascript to manipulate DOM elements heavily to create new UI depending on certain events. Client-side rendering becomes slower and slower as the app grows and I'm looking for a way to improve it. Specifically, I want to create a DOM element that is a clone of an html page (which is rendered on server-side completely), then insert this element into the existing web app. That would be inserting one big DOM element instead of manipulating many little elements heavily. That's the idea but I'm not sure if it's possible, and if so, how can I do that? If it's not possible, is there any better way to move most of the client-side rendering work to server?

Thanks,
H

Comment: Since the server can't send DOM elements to the browser (only text that the browser will read as tagsoup), I fail to understand the question since it almost seems as if you want a 'regular' php(etc.) site.. Other than that, you might want to look into [DocumentFragment](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) and/or cloning nodes including their children (but not attributes): `cloneNode(true);`. You could send raw html-strings over AJAX/JSON to prevent page-reload. Is this what you are after? Also, you could use a different processing thread (webworker) to generate html and pass it back.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use here is AJAX, AKA XMLHttpRequest.

```js
function getRequest(url, callbackFunction, target)
{
 var httpRequest;

 if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {
  //Modern Web Browsers
  httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else if(window.ActiveXObject)
 {
  //Old Microsoft Browsers
  try
  {
   httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
  catch (e)
  {
   try
   {
    httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   catch (e) {}
  }
 }

 if(!httpRequest)
 {
  alert('AJAX call failed! Please ensure you are using a supported web browser!');
  return false;
 }

 httpRequest.open('get', url, true);

 httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
 {
  var completed = 4, successful = 200;

  if(httpRequest.readyState == completed)
  {
   if(httpRequest.status == successful)
   {
    var data = httpRequest.responseText;
    callbackFunction(data, target);
   }
   else
   {
    alert('There was a problem with the request');
   }
  }
 }

 httpRequest.send(null);
}
```

This function is passed a url, aka "stuffIneed.html", "usefulinfo.xml", or "processthis.php" and contacts the server behind the scenes. This is asynchronous but can be made synchronous if you really need it to be.

This way, you could have the html generated in a PHP (or other language) script and then simply echo it back.

The target is an element id for the data to go inside and the callback function is a JavaScript function for you to process the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, have your server render components by name. Like widget1.html.

widget1.html could contain

```
<div class="widget1-wrapper">
   widget elements here
</div>
```

In the containing page, add

```
<iframe src="widget1.html" id="widget1" class="hide"></iframe>
<script>
  $(function(){
     $('#widget1').load(function(){
        var myWidget1Object = $(this).contents().find('.widget1-wrapper').clone(true);
     });
  });
</script>
```